# Using .keystore file to sign the request

Tags: java, web, service, keystore

I am trying to send a SOAP request to an application using web services (Java
). I have created a .keystore file containing the certificate using keytool. I am facing issues to use this .keystore file to sign the request XML...

Comment: Is your server HTTPS enabled? Please elaborate what are you doing in your code!

Comment: I am using Axis toolkit for sending soap request. I need to know that how to intercept SOAP messages sent out by the stubs, sign them and forward these signed messages onwards to their intended destination.